# Scrollable GridView for iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am implementing a Table for iPad and facing some major problems.

For the GridView I implemented my own subclass of UITableViewCell which works fine.

The data is shown correctly, but I have a problem when I want to access a single cell to go to some new detail view. Since one row only contains one cell, the didSelectRowAtIndexPath only gives me access to the complete cell, but I don't know which column the single cell is in.

Then I implemented a TapGestureRecognizer. This shows me the row and column and works, but only until I start scrolling... the column part still works, but the row is shown incorrect since the TapRecognizer overlaps the didSelectRowAtIndexPath (bad but not so important side effect.. there is no blue highlighting of the selected row).

Is there a way to find out how many pixels I scrolled? Or is there an even better solution?

Comment: Yes, there is a much better solution - it is called `UICollectionView`

Comment: If you are planning to target iOS 5.x then you might want to look at PSTCollectionView (https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView). It is a 100% API compatible replacement for UICollectionView. In fact, on iOS 6 it will transparently use UICollectionView instead, and fall back to PSTCollectionView on iOS 5.x and earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend using `UICollectionView` over those 3rd party classes. There are quite a few advantages to having access to all of the delegate protocols (like showing the cut copy paste `UIMenuController` on a long press without a `UIGestureRecognizer`, for example) I use one myself as a grid.

To acheive a grid layout, I did the following...

**1)** I set the following Delegates in my .h file:

```
@interface YourViewControllerWithCollectionView : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout> {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UICollectionView *myCollectionView;

@end
```

Notice, that I did not set the `UICollectionViewDelegate` because `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` is actually a sub-protocol of `UICollectionViewDelegate`, so there is no need to set both.

**2)** In the .m file, synthesize the collection view, and in viewDidLoad declare the datasource and delegates: (don't forget to connect your outlets, and you might want to put a background color on the cell so you can see it)

```
@synthesize myCollectionView;
```

viewdidLoad:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    self.myCollectionView.delegate = self;
    self.myCollectionView.dataSource = self;

    //...

    }
```

3) Implement the datasource

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionView Datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {

        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        //the number of cells you want per row
        return 4;
    }

    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        //load sublassed UICollectionViewCell called MyCollectionViewCell

        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
        MyCustomCollectionViewCell *cell = (MyCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

                cell.title.text = @"Title"
                // customize the cell...

        return cell;
```

}

**5)** Implement the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

```
#pragma mark – UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //this is what forces the collectionview to only display 4 cells for both orientations. Changing the "-80" will adjust the horizontal space between the cells.
    CGSize retval = CGSizeMake((myCollectionView.frame.size.width - 80) / 4, 78);

    return retval;
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

    // for the entire section, which we have set to 1, adjust the space at 
    // (top, left, bottom, right)
    // keep in mind if you change this, you will need to adjust the retVal
    // in the method above

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 20, 10, 20);
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

    CGFloat interimSpacing = 0.0f;

    return interimSpacing;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

    CGFloat lineSpacing = 0.0f;

    return lineSpacing;
}
```

**6)** Last, but certainly not least, invalidate the layout on orientation change to redraw the cells:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                               duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

    [self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];

}
```

And because you implemented `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, you already have access to `UICollectionViewDelegate` to handle selection, etc. like:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCollectionViewCell *cell = (MyCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   //do something when a cell is tapped...
}
```

More information can be found here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Comment: I did not use all of that, but thank you anyway for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) or some of the other [controls at CocoaControls.com](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=grid).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend AGAINST UICollectionView. UICollectionView is easy to use, but not stable enough at this moment. I am using [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView) for my apps. After a few months operations, I can say that it is stable enough for the production release. Another alternative is PSTCollectionView, which is a 100% API compatible replacement for UICollectionView. However, it is unfinished and contains even [more bugs](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView/issues?state=open) than UICollectionView.

The disturbing issues I have with PSTCollectionView are:

1. [poor performance](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView/issues/110) if you want to display > 80 cells on screen
2. reloading sections is [not implemented](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView/issues/174)
3. decoration views are [not implemented](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView/issues/237)

The disturbing issues I have with UICollectionView are:

1. the items in the first column may [disappear](https://openradar.appspot.com/12433891)
2. inserting the first cell will [crash](https://openradar.appspot.com/13133715)
3. reloading sections with header view will [crash](https://openradar.appspot.com/12954582)
4. [blurry text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098886/uicollectionviewflowlayout-doesnt-use-integral-frames) in cells

Check open radar
https://openradar.appspot.com/search?query=UICollectionView
for all current issues with UICollectionView.

I believe UICollectionView and PSTCollectionView will be good choices when they are stable. But at this moment, [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView) is a better choice.

Comment: GMGridView: 100 open issues. PSTCollectionView: 19 open issues. Your argument seems invalid.

Comment: GMGridView is no longer maintained, therefore all issues are left unresolved. But it is very stable before the author stops maintaining it. PSTCollectionView, on the other hand, is new and unfinished.