# UICollectionViewFlowLayout doesn't use integral frames

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6, uicollectionview

I have recently started using UICollectionView, and am a bit confused about the UICollectionViewFlowLayout. It would seem that the frames for each cell in the collection view are calculated with equal space between each item. This causes the frames of some of the cells to have fractional positions, which will cause blurry labels and misaligned image pixels and so on.

I am surprised to find that there are no questions about this on stack overflow though, which makes me think I am doing something wrong. I have created a test project that demonstrates the problem quite simply:

https://github.com/rmaz/BlurryCollectionView

Is this really the standard behaviour? It seems to me that this makes the flow layout basically unusable without subclassing. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I got the same bug. My solution is to use a sectionInset which will make the cell frames aligned.

Comment: This works if you have a layout that does not need to rotate, but it is not possible to use the same insets for both orientations if your cells have to follow a strict design. Why are we even fighting the layout like this? Odd implementation if you ask me.

Comment: You have to set the sectionInset for different orientations in "viewWillLayoutSubviews". I found that UICollectionView is not as productive as it seems, but it is too late for me to switch to other alternatives.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I am rapidly coming to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 8):

Workaround: subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, override `UICollectionViewLayout`'s `-layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` and for every layout attributes make the frame integral:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray *allLayoutAttributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes in allLayoutAttributes) {
        layoutAttributes.frame = CGRectIntegral(layoutAttributes.frame);
    }
    return allLayoutAttributes;
}
```

Note: iOS 7 `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` has been fixed to always use integral frames for its cells' frames. I recommend keeping the fix for iOS 6.x but conditionally deprecate it for iOS 7 and newer.

Best,
Raphael

Comment: This is not an ideal workaround, as it will cause uneven spacing between the cells.

Comment: You will by definition have uneven spacing if you want to have integral cells in a width that is not dividable without rest.

Comment: This is true, but I think you get a visually nicer result by increasing the right section inset until you get even spacing between each of the items in a row.

Comment: Often this option is not available within the given layout constraints or just not desired. If you still require integral frames e.g. to avoid blurry labels, the proposed solution seems like helping most people.